# function which takes 3 argument

Tags: javascript

I would like to have a function which takes 3 arguments:
sentence (string), 
maxCharLen=20 (number), 
separator (string)

Here is my example:
Should it be possible to improve this code?

```
function breakSentence(sentence) {
   var newstring,
       maxCharLen = 20,
       separator = ',';
   for(var i=0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
      newstring += sentence.charAt(i);
      if ((i % maxCharLen) === 0) {
         newstring += separator;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Interesting homework they assign these days.  If you want assistance perhaps you might post what you've already tried.

Comment: hint: string.substring(from, to)

Comment: You should definitely try before asking....

Comment: What does the `20` related to in your example?

Comment: A "delimiter" is something that acts as a boundary within a string. A "delimeter" is a measurement unit used primarily when measuring sandwiches.

Answer (score 1):

Rough example...

```
function breakSentence(sentence, maxCharLen, separator) {
   var newstring = "";
   for(i=0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
      newstring += sentence.charAt(i);
      if (((i % maxCharLen) == 0) & (i >= maxCharLen)) {
         newstring += separator;
      }
   }
}
```